# Why the ideals here are in this form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

In [this article](http://www.math.utah.edu/~ciubo/6310/6310_midterm_sol.pdf), in the proof of problem no. 6, p. 3, it listed all the possible ideals, because they contains at least one of $2$, $3$, $5$, from $120$. And at least one of $x+1$, $x^2-x+1$. But I think it is also possible to contain $2$ elements from $2$, $3$, $5$.  And $2$ elements from  $x+1$, $x^2-x+1$. In other words, why it is not possible for the ideal of the form $(2, 3, x+1)$? In addition, even if in the case it contains only $2$ and $x+1$,does it mean the ideal should be generated by $2$ and $x+1$,i.e., the ideal $(2, 3, x+1)$?  Apparently if an ideal contains $2$ and $x+1$, it can be possible in the form like $(2, 7, x+1)$. I feel confused about this one. Could you give me some ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an ideal in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ contains both $2$ and $3$, it contains $\operatorname{gcd}(2, 3) = 1$.  Then the ideal is all of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.  It's not that you can't have such an ideal; it's just redundant.  You can describe it with fewer generators (and you should).